# MVC Webgrid not being updated with new model values (using ajax POST)

Tags: json, ajax, model-view-controller, partial-views, webgrid

I tried to find a similar question with answer without luck. Hope I will explain myself better now than in previous questions.

The general outline:
I have a webapplication in MVC and in a partialview I have a webgrid and a date input. When the partial view is loadedd it creates a viewmodel "ViewReturnsModel", fills it with data from a webservice and returns it with the PartialView("ViewModel"). The model has a list of objects (DayData) which are shown in a webgrid.. With javascript I am able to update a property and save it to a database through a webservice.

Default, the date is today and the webgrid has seven rows, monday to sunday.
My problem is, when I choose another date and press the button it rerieves the chosen date and makes a post call to the views actionResult method. There it gets a new list of days to show in the webgrid, and returns the partial view with updated viewmodel. All the properties are correct on the model. But, the webgrid is not updated. I cannot find out what is the problem, why the models list of days arent read into the webgrid again :/

First is a view containing the partial view:

```
@model ViewModels.ViewReturnsModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Leveranser";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="tableDiv">
    @Html.Action("DeliveryTableView", "Home", Model)
</div>
```

Then in my controller I have an ActionResult for the partial view:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult DeliveryTableView(ViewReturnsModel model)
{
ModelState.Clear();
// Inside here just code for editing and validating the model.
// It creates a Viewmodel object, populates it with values retrieved from a webservice. Lastly it returns the updated viewmodel to the view.
return PartialView(deliveryModel);
}
```

The model is simple, just contains some properties:

```
public class ViewReturnsModel
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate{get;set;}
    public List<DayData> DeliveryDayList { get; set; }
}
```

In the PartialView I first have the div with the date input:

```
@model ViewModels.ViewReturnsModel
<div id="DateDiv">
    <input id="date" type="date" name="date1" value=@Model.FromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") />
    <input id="execute" type="button" value="Choose date" />
    <span id="dateObject"></span>
</div>
```

Then I have the webgrid:

```
    <div id="ajaxgrid">
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model.DeliveryDayList, ajaxUpdateCallback: "dateupdate", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "ajaxgrid", rowsPerPage: 7);

        IEnumerable<WebGridColumn> cols =
            new List<WebGridColumn> {

                new WebGridColumn{
                    Header="Day",
                    Format = @<text>
                        <span class="display"><label id="lblDay">@item.Day</label></span>
                        <input type="text" id="inDay" value="@item.Day" class="edit" readonly="true" />
                    </text>
                },
                new WebGridColumn{
                    Header="Date",
                    Format = @<text>
                        <span class="display"><label id="lblDate">@item.Date</label></span>
                        <input type="text" id="inDate" value="@item.Date" class="edit" readonly="false" />
                    </text>
                },
                new WebGridColumn{
                    Header="Ordered",
                    Format = @<text>
                        <span class="display"><label id="lblOrdered">@item.Ordered</label></span>
                        <input type="text" id="inOrdered" value="@item.Ordered" class="edit" readonly="true" />
                    </text>
                },
                new WebGridColumn{
                    Header="Delivered",
                    Format = @<text>
                        <span class="display"><label id="lblDelivered">@item.Delivered</label></span>
                        <input type="text" id="inDelivered" value="@item.Delivered" class="edit" readonly="true" />
                    </text>
                },
                new WebGridColumn{
                    Header="Returned",
                    Format = @<text>
                        <span class="display"><label id="lblReturned">@item.Returned</label></span>
                        <input type="text" id="inReturned" value="@item.Returned" class="edit" />
                    </text>
                },
                new WebGridColumn{
                    Format = @<text>
                        <a href='#' class="display edit-btn">Edit</a>
                        <a href="#" class="edit save-btn">Save</a>
                        <a href="#" class="edit cancel-btn">Close</a>
                    </text>
                }
            };
    }
</div>

@grid.GetHtml(columns: cols, tableStyle: "webGrid", rowStyle: "oddRowStyle", alternatingRowStyle: "evenRowStyle")
```

And then comes the scripts. First the code for getting a date into a field:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#execute").bind("click", function () {
        var dateString = $("#date").val();
        var date = new Date(dateString);

        updateDeliveryTable(date);

        $("#dateObject").text(date.toString());
    });
});
```

Then the function being called pressing the button to get the date:

```
function updateDeliveryTable(date) {
    var newDate = date;

    var ViewReturnsModel = {
        "FromDate": newDate
    };

    function onSuccess(result) {
        tr.find('.edit, .display').toggle();
        alert("Successfully Saved");
    }

    function onError() {
        alert("Error. Please, check the data");
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/DeliveryTableView/',
        data: JSON.stringify(ViewReturnsModel),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    });
}
```

The code for saving en edit to the model in the webgrid works nice, but here is the script. I followed a tutorial.

```
$(function ()
{
    var tfootAdd = "<tr class='tfootrow'>" +
                "<td> " +
                    "<a href='#' class='display ins-btn' >Insert</a>" +
                    "<a href='#' class='edit inssave-btn'>Save</a>" +
                    "<a href='#' class='edit cancel-btn'>Close</a>" +
                "</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                    "<span class='display'/>" +
                    "<input type='text' id='inID' value='' class = 'edit'/> " +
                    "</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                    "<span class='display'/>" +
                    "<input type='text' id='inName' value='' class = 'edit'/>" +
                "</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                    "<span class='display'/>" +
                    "<input type='text' id='inEmail' value='' class = 'edit'/>" +
                "</td>" +
            "</tr>"
    $("table tfoot tr:first").before(tfootAdd);

    $('.edit').hide();  // default is display

    $('.ins-btn, .edit-btn, .cancel-btn').on("click", function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        tr.find('.edit, .display').toggle();
    });


    // Javascript code to update the return
    $('.save-btn').on("click", function () {

        var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        var date = tr.find("#inDate").val();
        var ordered = tr.find("#inOrdered").val();
        var delivered = tr.find("#inDelivered").val();
        var returned = tr.find("#inReturned").val();
        var isSuccess = -1;

        tr.find("#lblOrdered").text(ordered);
        tr.find("#lblDelivered").text(delivered);
        tr.find("#lblReturned").text(returned);

        var ReturnDay =
        {
            "Date": date,
            "Returned": returned
        };

        $.ajax({

            url: '/Home/SaveReturn/',
            data: JSON.stringify(ReturnDay),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                isSuccess = result;
            },
            error: function (result) {
                isSuccess = result;
            }

        }).done(function () {
            if (isSuccess == "1") {           // Successfully saved
                tr.find('.edit, .display').toggle();
                alert("Successfully Saved");
            }
            else {                      // Data Error
                alert("Error. Please, check the data TEST");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Hope the code is enough, and Im sure that some of you experienced something obvious i have missed. Thanks,

Morten